# How to debug render overflow in VS Code for my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, debugging, widget, overflow, flutter-getx

I am writing Flutter app which uses Getx for states and routes management.
Screen design is imported from Figma using dhiwise.com, but some widget renderring is overflow.
This message I'm getting in the debugging console when I switch to some screens on my phone.
Each screen is in the safe area.

the Example code of a page overflows is here.

How to solve this problems?

Best regards,

Darko

```
import 'controller/customers_controller.dart';
import 'models/customers_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:pe_fahrzeuge_app/core/app_export.dart';

// ignore_for_file: must_be_immutable
class CustomersPage extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomersController controller =
      Get.put(CustomersController(CustomersModel().obs));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: getHorizontalSize(27.00),
                      right: getHorizontalSize(27.00)),
                  child: Text("msg_search_customer".tr,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: AppStyle.textStyleRobotoromanregular14
                          .copyWith(fontSize: getFontSize(14))))),
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: getHorizontalSize(15.00),
                  top: getVerticalSize(8.00),
                  right: getHorizontalSize(15.00)),
              child: Container(
                  height: getVerticalSize(41.00),
                  width: getHorizontalSize(384.00),
                  child: TextFormField(
                      controller: controller.nikolaMarojeviController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "msg_nikola_marojevi".tr,
                          hintStyle: AppStyle.textStyleRobotoromanregular16.copyWith(
                              fontSize: getFontSize(16.0),
                              color: ColorConstant.gray602),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                  getHorizontalSize(20.00)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: ColorConstant.bluegray100, width: 1)),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                  getHorizontalSize(20.00)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: ColorConstant.bluegray100, width: 1)),
                          prefixIcon: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: getHorizontalSize(16.00), right: getHorizontalSize(10.00)), child: Container(height: getSize(32.00), width: getSize(32.00), child: SvgPicture.asset(ImageConstant.imgSearchIcon1, fit: BoxFit.contain))),
                          prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: getSize(32.00), minHeight: getSize(32.00)),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
                          isDense: true,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: getVerticalSize(4.00), bottom: getVerticalSize(4.00))),
                      style: TextStyle(color: ColorConstant.gray602, fontSize: getFontSize(16.0), fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)))),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: getVerticalSize(27.00)),
                  decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(color: ColorConstant.whiteA700, boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: ColorConstant.gray60040,
                        spreadRadius: getHorizontalSize(2.00),
                        blurRadius: getHorizontalSize(2.00),
                        offset: Offset(0, 4))
                  ]),
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            height: getVerticalSize(1.00),
                            width: size.width,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: ColorConstant.bluegray101)),
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: getVerticalSize(19.00),
                                bottom: getVerticalSize(20.00)),
                            child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: getHorizontalSize(21.00)),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                              getHorizontalSize(32.50)),
                                          border: Border.all(
                                              color: ColorConstant.red800,
                                              width: getHorizontalSize(1.00))),
                                      child: Column(
                                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    left: getHorizontalSize(
                                                        17.00),
                                                    top: getVerticalSize(27.00),
                                                    right: getHorizontalSize(
                                                        17.00),
                                                    bottom:
                                                        getVerticalSize(26.00)),
                                                child: Text("lbl_nm".tr,
                                                    overflow:
                                                        TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                    style: AppStyle
                                                        .textStyleInterblack18
                                                        .copyWith(
                                                            fontSize:
                                                                getFontSize(
                                                                    18))))
                                          ])),
                                  Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: getHorizontalSize(16.00),
                                          right: getHorizontalSize(12.69)),
                                      child: Column(
                                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                                width:
                                                    getHorizontalSize(299.31),
                                                child: Row(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                                        MainAxisAlignment
                                                            .spaceBetween,
                                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                                        CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                                    mainAxisSize:
                                                        MainAxisSize.max,
                                                    children: [
                                                      Padding(
                                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                              bottom:
                                                                  getVerticalSize(
                                                                      1.00)),
                                                          child: Text(
                                                              "lbl_al_fresco"
                                                                  .tr,
                                                              overflow:
                                                                  TextOverflow
                                                                      .ellipsis,
                                                              textAlign:
                                                                  TextAlign
                                                                      .left,
                                                              style: AppStyle
                                                                  .textStyleInterbold161
                                                                  .copyWith(
                                                                      fontSize:
                                                                          getFontSize(
                                                                              16)))),
                                                      GestureDetector(
                                                          onTap: () {
                                                            onTapGroup43();
                                                          },
                                                          child: Padding(
                                                              padding: EdgeInsets
                                                                  .only(
                                                                      top: getVerticalSize(
                                                                          7.00)),
                                                              child: Row(
                                                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                      CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                          .center,
                                                                  mainAxisSize:
                                                                      MainAxisSize
                                                                          .min,
                                                                  children: [
                                                                    Padding(
                                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                            top: getVerticalSize(
                                                                                2.00),
                                                                            bottom: getVerticalSize(
                                                                                1.38)),
                                                                        child: Container(
                                                                            height:
                                                                                getSize(9.62),
                                                                            width: getSize(9.62),
                                                                            child: SvgPicture.asset(ImageConstant.imgVector9, fit: BoxFit.fill))),
                                                                    Padding(
                                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                            left: getHorizontalSize(
                                                                                5.69)),
                                                                        child: Text(
                                                                            "msg_edit_client_inf"
                                                                                .tr,
                                                                            overflow:
                                                                                TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                                            style: AppStyle.textStyleInterbold11.copyWith(fontSize: getFontSize(11))))
                                                                  ])))
                                                    ])),
                                            Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    top: getVerticalSize(5.00),
                                                    right: getHorizontalSize(
                                                        10.00)),
                                                child: Text("lbl_24_07_1992".tr,
                                                    overflow:
                                                        TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                    style: AppStyle
                                                        .textStyleIntermedium15
                                                        .copyWith(
                                                            fontSize:
                                                                getFontSize(
                                                                    15)))),
                                            Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    top: getVerticalSize(6.00),
                                                    right: getHorizontalSize(
                                                        10.00)),
                                                child: Text(
                                                    "lbl_068_939_393".tr,
                                                    overflow:
                                                        TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                    style: AppStyle
                                                        .textStyleInterregular13
                                                        .copyWith(
                                                            fontSize:
                                                                getFontSize(
                                                                    13))))
                                          ]))
                                ]))
                      ]))),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: getHorizontalSize(27.00),
                      top: getVerticalSize(20.00),
                      right: getHorizontalSize(27.00)),
                  child: Text("lbl_a".tr,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: AppStyle.textStylePoppinsbold18
                          .copyWith(fontSize: getFontSize(18))))),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: getHorizontalSize(15.00),
                      right: getHorizontalSize(15.00)),
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text("lbl_a".tr,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: AppStyle.textStylePoppinssemibold12
                                .copyWith(fontSize: getFontSize(12))),
                        Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: getVerticalSize(5.00)),
                            child: Text("lbl_b".tr,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: AppStyle.textStylePoppinssemibold12
                                    .copyWith(fontSize: getFontSize(12)))),
                        Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: getVerticalSize(5.00)),
                            child: Text("lbl_c".tr,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: AppStyle.textStylePoppinssemibold12
                                    .copyWith(fontSize: getFontSize(12)))),
                        Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: getVerticalSize(5.00)),
                            child: Text("lbl_d".tr,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: AppStyle.textStylePoppinssemibold12
                                    .copyWith(fontSize: getFontSize(12)))),
                        Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: getVerticalSize(5.00)),
                            child: Text("lbl_e".tr,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: AppStyle.textStylePoppinssemibold12
                                    .copyWith(fontSize: getFontSize(12)))),
                        Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: getVerticalSize(5.00)),
                            child: Text("lbl_f".tr,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: AppStyle.textStylePoppinssemibold12
                                    .copyWith(fontSize: getFontSize(12)))),
                        Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: getVerticalSize(5.00)),
                            child: Text("lbl_g".tr,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: AppStyle.textStylePoppinssemibold12
                                    .copyWith(fontSize: getFontSize(12)))),
                        Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: getVerticalSize(5.00)))));
}
}
```